# How to query MYSQL when clicked?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a while statement, echoing my whole database that match a WHERE parameter. How can I make it so when I click on something (anything for the moment), it updates that specific row. Here's my code.

```
                    while($request = mysql_fetch_array( $request_db )) {
                    echo "<tr><td style=\"width:33%;padding:1px;\">";
                    echo $request['SongName'];  
                    echo "</td><td style=\"width:33%;\">";
                    echo $request['Artist'];    
                    echo "</td><td style=\"width:33%;\">";
                    echo $request['DedicatedTo'];
                    echo "</td><td style=\"width:33%;\">";
                    echo "UPDATE A ROW's 'Hasplayed' value to '1'.";
                    echo "</td></tr>";  
                }
                echo "</table>";
```

Thanks!

EDIT: If you want an example, PHPmyAdmin can do this. Could I use some sort temporary cookie?

Comment: Comments seem to point towards ajax but you didn't indicate whether a page reload is allowed on click or not.

Comment: Apologies, I don't mind a page reload :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a form and a button.
And update your table usual way, by handling this form with some PHP script.

You will need such a script anyway. Because no browser nor cookie can have access to your database. But only PHP script.

You can add to this script AJAX functionality later.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but does a form require some sort of <input>?

Comment: @Sam sure it does. though you can use javascript "onclick" property on any element, if you wish. what kind of control you want?

Comment: but you'd better to do it step by step. Add `input type = "submit"` first to test if it ever works

Comment: Is it possible to do this WITHOUT an input? Would it be as simple as adding a name attribute to a <p> or <div>, and whatever is in is is sent through?

Comment: Why must I use JavaScript to do this? I'm under the impression that all I have to do is wrap the text I want to send through in a <p>, <div> or <span> and then wrap that in a form like a normal form. Are there any tutorials or SO questions? A name for this process?

Comment: @Sam it is basic HTML question. The number of controls you can use  is quite limited. To send a form to a server you can use either submit button or a javascript event emulating it. That's all.

Comment: I don't mind using a submit button, but the actual values of what the submit button would send, do these have to be <input> values?

Comment: @Sam yes. But what's the problem with it? Have no idea of hidden input types may be?

Comment: @Sam note that you can pass a variable not only using value, but also name of the input: `<input type="submit" name=id[273] value="Update">`. and you will have `$_POST['id'][273]="Update"` in your script. Or hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

Give the rows an id and do an ajax request via a link with the id of the db element as parameter. The server script reloads that db id and returns the fresh database values. :)

Comment: Are there any other ways to achieve this? I am not very experienced in AJAX.